# Why is clear:both not working?

Tags: html, css

I want to place a div below another, namely the text test should be place below the map. How can I achieve it? I want to put content below the map but it won't render in the right place. I want the div which contains the text text to render diretly below the map and prefeably take all the free space. How can that be done?

[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords"
          content="Houses Apartments, Vacation homes, Offices, Land, Flatmates,Paying Guest, Other real estate, Cars, Motorcycles, Accessories  parts, Trucks, Other vehicles, Home  Garden, Clothing, For Kids (Toys  Clothes), Jewelry  Watches, Hobbies, Sports  Bicycles, Movies, Books  Magazines, Pets, Tickets, Art  Collectibles, Music  Instruments, Computers  Accessories, TV, Audio, Video, Cameras, Cellphones  gadgets, Video games  consoles, Job offers, Resumes, Services, Classes, Professional,Office equipment, Other,  ">
    <meta name="description"
          content="Find jobs, cars, houses, mobile phones and properties for sale in your region conveniently. Find the best deal among {{count}} free ads online!">

    <title>Free classifieds in India - Koolbusiness.com</title>

    <link href="/static/css/koolindex_in.css?0.238133053892" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?0.238133053892"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        #visualization path:hover { fill: #fcafff;stroke:'#FFFFFF';strokeWidth:155;  }
        #visualization rect:hover {fill:transparent;stroke:'#FFFFFF';strokeWidth:155;}
      </style>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>


        function drawMap() {
            /*
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Projects'],
        ['Russia', 3],
        ['France', 2],
        ['Spain', 4]
    ]);*/
            var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Goa', 200],
      ['Gujarat', 300],['Andhra Pradesh', 200],
['Arunachal Pradesh', 300],['Assam', 200],
['Bihar', 300],['Chhattisgarh', 200],
['Gujarat', 300],['Goa', 200],
['Haryana', 300],['Himachal Pradesh', 200],
['Jammu and Kashmir', 300],['Jharkhand', 200],
['Karnataka', 300],['Kerala', 200],
['Madhya Pradesh', 300],['Maharashtra', 200],['Manipur', 300],['Meghalaya', 200],['Mizoram', 300],['Nagaland', 200],



























                ['Orissa', 300],['Punjab', 200],
                ['Rajasthan', 300],
                ['Sikkim', 200],
                ['Tamil Nadu', 300],
                ['Tripura', 200],

                         ['Uttaranchal', 300],['Uttar Pradesh', 200],
                ['West Bengal', 300],
                ['Delhi', 200],
                ['Lakshadweep', 300],
                ['Daman and Diu', 200],

                         ['Dadra and Nagar Haveli', 300],['Chandigarh', 200],
                ['Pondicherry', 300],
                ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 200]

    ]);
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Province'],
        ['Goa'],
        ['Gujarat'],

         ['Andhra Pradesh'],
['Arunachal Pradesh'],
['Assam'],
['Bihar'],
['Chhattisgarh'],
['Goa'],
['Gujarat'],
['Haryana'],
['Himachal Pradesh'],
['Jammu and Kashmir'],
['Jharkhand'],
['Karnataka'],
['Kerala'],
['Madhya Pradesh'],
['Maharashtra'],
['Manipur'],
['Meghalaya'],
['Mizoram'],
['Nagaland'],
['Orissa'],
['Punjab'],
['Rajasthan'],
['Sikkim'],
['Tamil Nadu'],
['Tripura'],
['Uttaranchal'],
['Uttar Pradesh'],
['West Bengal'],
['Delhi'],
['Lakshadweep'],
['Daman and Diu'],
['Dadra and Nagar Haveli'],
['Chandigarh'],
['Pondicherry'],
['Andaman and Nicobar Islands']



    ]);



 var options = {
           region:'IN',
          /*colorAxis: {colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23']},*/
//colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: []},
          backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
          datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
      width:450,
       height:278,
     resolution: 'provinces',
        };
//options['colorAxis'] = { minValue : 0, maxValue : 1, colors : ['#FF0000','#0000FF']};
        options['colors'] = ['#ffc801', '#ffc801', '#ffc801', '#ffc801', '#ffc801', '#ffc801', '#ffc801', '#ffc801', '#ffc801', '#ffc801'];
        options['legend'] = 'none';

            /*
       var options = {  dataMode: 'regions',
       backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:25 },
       colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: []},
       legend: 'none',
       datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
       displayMode: 'regions',
       enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
       resolution: 'provinces',
       sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
       region:'IN',
       keepAspectRatio: true,
       width:450,
       height:300,
       tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus', isHtml: false}
       };*/
    var container = document.getElementById('mapcontainer');
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);

    function myClickHandler(){
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        var message = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            var item = selection[i];
           // if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {
                message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '}';
            //} else
             if (item.row != null) {
                message += '{row:' + item.row + '}';
            //} else if (item.column != null) {
              //  message += '{column:' + item.column + '}';
            }
        }
        if (message == '') {
            message = 'nothing';
        }
        alert('You selected ' + message);
        if (item.row==8) {
             window.location = "/gujarat/";
        }if (item.row==9) {
             window.location = "/haryana/";
        }
        if (item.row==15) {
             window.location = "/madhya_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==16) {
             window.location = "/maharashtra/";
        }
         if (item.row==22) {
             window.location = "/punjab/";
        }
          if (item.row==23) {
             window.location = "/rajasthan/";
        }
          if (item.row==28) {
             window.location = "/uttar_pradesh/";
        }
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart'], callback: drawMap});






      /*


        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

       data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
       data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});var ivalue = new Array();

       var options = {
       backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:25 },
       colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: []},
       legend: 'none',
       datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
       displayMode: 'regions',
       enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
       resolution: 'provinces',
       sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
       region:'IN',
       keepAspectRatio: true,
       width:450,
       height:300,
       tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus', isHtml: false}
       };
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        if (selection.length == 1) {
        var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
        var selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
        if(ivalue[selectedRegion] != '') { document.location = ivalue[selectedRegion];  }
        }
        });
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }*/
     </script>

<div id="wrapper">

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<div class="alert-outer alert-error">
    <a href="#" class="alert-closer" title="close this alert" onclick="removeIeNotification(this); return false;">×</a>

    <div class="alert-inner">
        <span><strong>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer.</strong> For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade today!</span>

    </div>
</div>

<![endif]-->

<div class="main">
<div class="column_left">
    <div class="box">

        <ul>
            <li>KoolBusiness is easy, free, and kool.</li>
            <li>Buy and sell <a href="/india/cars-for_sale">cars</a>, check our <a href="/india/real_estate">real
                estate</a>
                section, find <a href="/india/jobs">jobs</a>, and much more.
            </li>
            <li>Check our <strong><a href="/india">0 ads online</a></strong> and find what you are looking for
                in
                your region or in all India.
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>

    <div id="regions">


        <div class="region_links_one">
            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/andhra_pradesh/">Andhra
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/arunachal_pradesh/">Arunachal
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/assam/">Assam</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/bihar/">Bihar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/chhattisgarh/">Chhattisgarh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/goa/">Goa</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/gujarat/">Gujarat</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/haryana/">Haryana</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_16" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/himachal_pradesh/">Himachal
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_17" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/jammu_kashmir/">Jammu
                    &amp;
                    Kashmir</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_18" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/jharkhand/">Jharkhand</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_19" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/karnataka/">Karnataka</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_20" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/kerala/">Kerala</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_21" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/madhya_pradesh/">Madhya
                    Pradesh</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a id="region_22" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/maharashtra/">Maharashtra</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_23" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/manipur/">Manipur</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_24" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/meghalaya/">Meghalaya</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_25" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/mizoram/">Mizoram</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_26" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/nagaland/">Nagaland</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_27" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/orissa/">Orissa</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_28" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/punjab/">Punjab</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_29" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/rajasthan/">Rajasthan</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_30" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/sikkim/">Sikkim</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_31" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/tamil_nadu/">Tamil
                    Nadu</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_32" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/tripura/">Tripura</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_34" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/uttaranchal/">Uttaranchal</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_33" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/uttar_pradesh/">Uttar
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_35" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/west_bengal/">West
                    Bengal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="region_links_two">
            <!-- ads here -->
            <h2>Union territories</h2>


            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/delhi/">Delhi</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/lakshadweep/">Lakshadweep</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/daman_diu/">Daman &amp; Diu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/dadra_nagar_haveli/">Dadra &amp; Nagar
                    Haveli</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/chandigarh/">Chandigarh</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/pondicherry/">Pondicherry</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/andaman_nicobar_islands/">Andaman &amp;
                    Nicobar
                    Islands</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="my_wrapper">
<div id="mapcontainer">

     <div id='visualization'></div>

</div>
<div>
test
</div>
</div>
<footer class="nohistory columns">

    <p class="first">A good deal is just around the corner!</p>


    <p>KoolBusiness is the right choice for safe buying and selling in India: a free classifieds website where you
        can buy and sell almost everything.</p>


    <p><a href="/ai">Post an ad for free</a> or browse through our categories. You will find thousands of free
        classifieds for cars, houses, mobile phones and gadgets, computers, pets and dozens of items and services in
        your state or union territory.</p>


    <p>

        <strong>KoolBusiness does not charge any fee and does not require registration.</strong> Every
        ad is checked so we can give you the highest quality possible for the ads on our site. That’s why
        KoolBusiness is the most convenient, easiest to use and most complete free ads site in India.</p>


    <div id="world_sites">





    </div>




</footer>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is available [here](http://pastebin.com/kxhQH0u6).

Comment: What is in `/static/css/koolindex_in.css`?

Comment: are you floating the element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably missing something—`clear:both` works just fine.

The `<div>` with "test" in it has no clearing applied, as far as I can see. I loaded your HTML into a new web page, changed the link to the CSS file, and could see the basic layout you have above.

Then I used Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature to review that element. No clearing was applied; when I added `clear:both` using Developer Tools, it popped below, as you asked.

:D

Edit: attached screenshot[image: screenshot shows Developer Tools in use]

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't see where it appeared. Now I want it to appear directly below the map to the right of the geographical names.

Comment: One option would be to float the names to the left, then float the map to the right. This block could then be set to `clear:right` rather than `clear:both`. Keep in mind that you may need the entire layout to be held within a container that is, itself, floated—if not, then if you have a sidebar floated right outside of this main layout, your div would come below it.

Comment: Another option would be to wrap the mapcontainer and the div with one floating div, and NOT float the mapcontainer...

Comment: Thank you. I'm going for the second alternative, wrap the divs and not float the mapcontainer.